# How to initialize a typescript class from existing object?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, initialization

This may be looking similar to previous questions, but I didn't find my answer, so I asked it here.
My example:

```
Class A{
  id:number;
  name:string;
}

Class B{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  age:number;
  grade:number;
}

const b = new B {id:1, name:'John', age: 20, grade: 10}
```

Now I want to initialize a new instance of class A only with two attributes from class B.
Something like this:

```
const a = b as A;
```

I need my result look like this:

```
a = {id:1, name:'John'}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

## Code

```
class A {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  static toA<T extends { id: number, name: string }>({ id, name }: T): A {
    const newObject = new A(id, name);
    return newObject;
  } 
}
```

### Explanation

It is not possible to change the runtime structure by only cheating TypeScript. `as` just tells TypeScript "Don't think too much, just assume `b` as `A`," and TypeScript won't do anything (including writing a B to A converter for you) except assuming the type of that object is `A` in the type-checking (compile) time.

So, We should write an explicit converter for it. We received any object with the required fields, then create a new `A` object with those fields.

### Examples

```js
class A {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  static toA<T extends { id: number, name: string }>({ id, name }: T): A {
    const newObject = new A(id, name);
    return newObject;
  } 
}

class B extends A {
  test: number;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, test: number) {
    super(id, name);
    this.test = test;
  }
}

const b = new B(1, "hi", 2);
console.log(A.toA(b)); // A { id: 1, name: 'hi' }
```